# redirect not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am working on a wordpress site. I have a link 
[Your Recent Search](http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/recent-member-search/)

when user click on it, it goes to another page which is a child template in wordpress. Here I have placed a wp_redirect. But the redirect doesn't work and user remains on that page. Here is the redirect code

```
$recent_user_ID = get_current_user_id();
echo $redirecUrl = get_user_meta($recent_user_ID,'recent_member_search', true); //this displays the correct url
wp_redirect( $redirecUrl ); exit; // but redirect is not working.
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_redirect()` needs an absolute URI otherwise it will return false.

Try this out and make sure its above the header

```
function members_search_redirect() {
    $recent_user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    $redirecUrl = get_site_url() . '/' . get_user_meta($recent_user_ID,'recent_member_search', true); 
    wp_redirect( $redirecUrl ); 
    exit; 
}

add_action('init', 'members_search_redirect');
```

Comment: but echo $redirctUrl gives me the correct url  http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/members/?zipcode=10001&field_distance=&field_4=&field_7=&field_10=&field_388=&field_386=&bs=+    so don't why use get_site_url().

Comment: Please click on the link in question "your Recent Search" It will go to the page where you can see the url printed...

Comment: what page are you trying to redirect it to?

Comment: this is the page where I want to redirect it        http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/members/?zipcode=10001&field_distance=&field_4=&field_7=&field_10=&field_388=&field_386=&bs=+

Comment: So is it the form your want to redirect, or when you go straight onto the recent-member-search page, that redirects?

Comment: Its not a form. I just want that when I go to recent-member-search page,  it should redirect to the other page..

Comment: I dont think you're running the code on the right page. i cant see an echo'd version of the code on `recent-member-search` whereas i can see the echo'd version on `members`

Comment: Please open this page. here you can see the echo'd url on recent-member-search page. below this echo'd code, there is wp-redirect but not working    http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/recent-member-search/

Comment: I see nothing on the page? Just so you know, re-directs need to be made before the html starts to load. try amended code above

Comment: Now I have replaced all code by above code. I doesn't show any thing.

Comment: can you see the echo'd url here    http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/recent-member-search/

Comment: There is no url being shown on that page. comment out the wp_redirect. The only thing i can think of is that the $redirecUrl is wrong the wp_redirect is returning false.

Comment: I just checked it in mozilla and there is no url displaying but in chrome the url is echo'd and you can view it.